# Remove only one element from string array using linq

Tags: c#-4.0

I have following code:

```
string[] s = {"one", "two", "three", "two", "Four"}; 
s = s.Where(x => x!="two").ToArray();
```

I want to remove "two" only once using linq is there a way to do this? Code i tried above removes both "two" elements from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you want to remove duplicates in general, then it's very simple:

```
s = s.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Otherwise you can use `GroupBy`:

```
s = s.GroupBy(str => str).SelectMany(g => g.Key != "two" ? g : g.Take(1)).ToArray();
```

This allows duplicates in general, but `two` must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the first occurrence :

```
var t = s.ToList();
t.Remove(value);
s = t.ToArray();
```

Otherwise it's the .Distinct() function